# redis-queue on Mac OS: process has forked and you cannot use this CoreFoundation functionality safely

Tags: python, macos, redis

I have a django app that makes use of rq queues. My setup was working fine on Ubuntu but my queue won't process any jobs on mac os (Catalina).

Basically, I have my django app running with `python manage.py runserver`
And I run my queue with `python3 manage.py rqworker default`

As soon as I send a job to the queue, I get this message (one such block per job):

```
07:10:41 default: djpager.jobs.pager.generate_source(331) (f799a0ae-1500-4483-a1ce-818995c93bed)
The process has forked and you cannot use this CoreFoundation functionality safely. You MUST exec().
Break on __THE_PROCESS_HAS_FORKED_AND_YOU_CANNOT_USE_THIS_COREFOUNDATION_FUNCTIONALITY___YOU_MUST_EXEC__() to debug.
objc[26643]: +[NSNumber initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called.
objc[26643]: +[NSNumber initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called. We cannot safely call it or ignore it in the fork() child process. Crashing instead. Set a breakpoint on objc_initializeAfterForkError to debug.
07:10:41 Moving job to FailedJobRegistry (work-horse terminated unexpectedly; waitpid returned 6)
```

Googling around, the only suggestion I found was executing this command:

```
export OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES
```

That makes the error message slightly shorter, but still no jobs are run:

```
07:23:26 default: djpager.jobs.pager.generate_source(362) (33fd1d39-5bc4-49b9-a1ee-c5fb0218fe95)
The process has forked and you cannot use this CoreFoundation functionality safely. You MUST exec().
Break on __THE_PROCESS_HAS_FORKED_AND_YOU_CANNOT_USE_THIS_COREFOUNDATION_FUNCTIONALITY___YOU_MUST_EXEC__() to debug.
07:23:26 Moving job to FailedJobRegistry (work-horse terminated unexpectedly; waitpid returned 11)
```

Any suggestions on how to get this to work on mac os?

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue on macOS Catalina 10.15.4 and Python 3.8.3, with code that worked just fine on Ubuntu 18.04.4. The issue is documented [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue33725).

I resolved it by putting the problematic call(s) inside `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem after the OS update.

According to [this](https://github.com/rq/django-rq/issues/375) github issue, Starting the worker with sudo solves the problem for now.